# Ruby - Can't write to file after checking if empty

Tags: ruby, file, fwrite, fread

The program should write `"File Empty"` if the file is empty; otherwise, it should write `"File Full"`. Here's what I have so far:

```
fname = "fileTest.txt"
somefile = File.open(fname, "w")

if File.readlines(somefile).grep(/monitor/).size == 0
    somefile.write("File Empty")
else
    somefile.write("File Full.")
end

somefile.close
```

When I run this the first time, `fileText.txt` is empty, so the program writes `"File Empty"`. When I run it a second time, the program should write `"File Full"`, but the file still reads `"File Empty"`.

The `if` statement should be checking if the file is empty, but I don't it is working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

> **EDIT - Problem Solved:**
>
> ```
> fname = "fileTest.txt"
> somefile = File.open(fname, "a")
>
> if File.zero?(somefile)
>   somefile.write("File Empty")
> else
>   somefile.write("File Full.")
> end
>
> somefile.close
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code doesn't really match your question.

You say:

> The program should write "File Empty" if the file is empty; otherwise,
>   it should write "File Full"

But you code says this:

```
if File.readlines(somefile).grep(/monitor/).size == 0
    somefile.write("File Empty")
else
    somefile.write("File Full.")
end
```

You are grepping for an RE that matches `monitor` and, if you don't find it, you're code says to write "File Empty".

"File Empty" does not contain "monitor", so when the program is run a second time, it once again reports "file empty"

If you are actually trying to solve the problem I quoted, then you can use [`File.zero?("filename")`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/File.html#method-c-zero-3F) as a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 4):

The "w" option in `File.open(fname,"w")` truncates the file if it exists or creates a new file if it does not exists- it will always be empty opened in this mode . See [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-new) for the options.

`File.readlines` does not need a file object, a string ("path/to/filename.txt"), or in this case `fname` will do.

Comment: Not enough for a complete answer, but maybe OP can also check whether `File.exist?()` returns true. If so, then proceeding to open/wrtite the file will _not_ create a new/empty one.

Comment: @onebree: [Avoid TOCTOU race conditions while accessing files](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/FIO45-C.+Avoid+TOCTOU+race+conditions+while+accessing+files) (about C but it also applies to other languages like Ruby)

Comment: Thanks Steenslag! I changed `File.open(fname, "w")` to `File.open(fname, "a")`. I want the program to append if the file is full.

Comment: @cremno Thank you for the link. I do not know much about race conditions in general, so this will be a good thing to read.